# Merge new query params into react router's current location

Tags: react-router

I have a react component that needs to update (push) the current location by adding a new query string parameter.

Example:

Current LOC: http://localhost/#/reports?state=open

After LOC: http://localhost/#/reports?state=open&category=2

After the update tell react router to navigate to the new location and some other component will pick up the change and filter some data...jadajadajada

I'm wrapping my component with (withRouter) to get access to the router object but I can't get my head around how to **first** get the current location (if I even need that?) and **secondly** how to add the new query.

Preferably I also would like to "merge" the location's query part with an object like {category:2} since the current location could be just /reports and not /reports?state=open.

Ideas, suggestions??

This is react router 2.4xxx (or the newest version as of this question at least)

Some basic code:

```
    class Filter extends Component {

    handleoOnSelectionChange(category){

        // HERE - push new location by adding {'category': category.id}
    }

    render() {

        ....
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
....
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, {location}) => {
...
};

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Filter))
```